# Ubuntu 18.04 shuts down 'randomly'

Tags: 18.04, shutdown

I use HP Omen laptop running Ubuntu 18.04 and it shuts down as if I was holding power off button. I managed to find logs around the moment it happens, but unfortunately I'm not able to interpret them. Critical moment I believe is around 18:34:31. Could anyone please help me?

Logs:

```
Dec 20 18:34:13 trancelestial PackageKit: resolve transaction /2002_eebcedae from uid 1000 finished with success after 334ms
Dec 20 18:34:13 trancelestial update-notifier.desktop[2804]: Cannot stat file /proc/2427/fd/1023: Permission denied
Dec 20 18:34:13 trancelestial update-notifier.desktop[2804]: Cannot stat file /proc/2608/fd/5: Permission denied
Dec 20 18:34:13 trancelestial update-notifier.desktop[2804]: Cannot stat file /proc/2608/fd/6: Permission denied
Dec 20 18:34:13 trancelestial update-notifier.desktop[2804]: Cannot stat file /proc/2608/fd/7: Permission denied
Dec 20 18:34:13 trancelestial update-notifier.desktop[2804]: Cannot stat file /proc/2608/fd/8: Permission denied
Dec 20 18:34:13 trancelestial update-notifier.desktop[2804]: Cannot stat file /proc/2608/fd/9: Permission denied
Dec 20 18:34:13 trancelestial update-notifier.desktop[2804]: Cannot stat file /proc/2608/fd/10: Permission denied
Dec 20 18:34:13 trancelestial update-notifier.desktop[2804]: Cannot stat file /proc/2608/fd/11: Permission denied
Dec 20 18:34:13 trancelestial update-notifier.desktop[2804]: Cannot stat file /proc/2608/fd/12: Permission denied
Dec 20 18:34:13 trancelestial update-notifier.desktop[2804]: Cannot stat file /proc/2608/fd/68: Permission denied
Dec 20 18:34:13 trancelestial update-notifier.desktop[2804]: Cannot stat file /proc/2608/fd/75: Permission denied
Dec 20 18:34:13 trancelestial update-notifier.desktop[2804]: Cannot stat file /proc/2608/fd/76: Permission denied
Dec 20 18:34:13 trancelestial update-notifier.desktop[2804]: Cannot stat file /proc/2608/fd/1023: Permission denied
Dec 20 18:34:13 trancelestial update-notifier.desktop[2804]: Cannot stat file /proc/2651/fd/6: Permission denied
Dec 20 18:34:13 trancelestial update-notifier.desktop[2804]: Cannot stat file /proc/2651/fd/7: Permission denied
Dec 20 18:34:13 trancelestial update-notifier.desktop[2804]: Cannot stat file /proc/2651/fd/8: Permission denied
Dec 20 18:34:13 trancelestial update-notifier.desktop[2804]: Cannot stat file /proc/2651/fd/9: Permission denied
Dec 20 18:34:13 trancelestial update-notifier.desktop[2804]: Cannot stat file /proc/2651/fd/10: Permission denied
Dec 20 18:34:13 trancelestial update-notifier.desktop[2804]: Cannot stat file /proc/2651/fd/11: Permission denied
Dec 20 18:34:13 trancelestial update-notifier.desktop[2804]: Cannot stat file /proc/2651/fd/12: Permission denied
Dec 20 18:34:13 trancelestial update-notifier.desktop[2804]: Cannot stat file /proc/2651/fd/13: Permission denied
Dec 20 18:34:13 trancelestial update-notifier.desktop[2804]: Cannot stat file /proc/2670/fd/4: Permission denied
Dec 20 18:34:13 trancelestial update-notifier.desktop[2804]: Cannot stat file /proc/2670/fd/6: Permission denied
Dec 20 18:34:13 trancelestial update-notifier.desktop[2804]: Cannot stat file /proc/2670/fd/7: Permission denied
Dec 20 18:34:13 trancelestial update-notifier.desktop[2804]: Cannot stat file /proc/2670/fd/8: Permission denied
Dec 20 18:34:13 trancelestial update-notifier.desktop[2804]: Cannot stat file /proc/2670/fd/9: Permission denied
Dec 20 18:34:13 trancelestial update-notifier.desktop[2804]: Cannot stat file /proc/2705/fd/6: Permission denied
Dec 20 18:34:13 trancelestial update-notifier.desktop[2804]: Cannot stat file /proc/2705/fd/7: Permission denied
Dec 20 18:34:13 trancelestial update-notifier.desktop[2804]: Cannot stat file /proc/2705/fd/8: Permission denied
Dec 20 18:34:13 trancelestial update-notifier.desktop[2804]: Cannot stat file /proc/2705/fd/9: Permission denied
Dec 20 18:34:13 trancelestial update-notifier.desktop[2804]: Cannot stat file /proc/2705/fd/10: Permission denied
Dec 20 18:34:13 trancelestial update-notifier.desktop[2804]: Cannot stat file /proc/2705/fd/11: Permission denied
Dec 20 18:34:13 trancelestial update-notifier.desktop[2804]: Cannot stat file /proc/2705/fd/12: Permission denied
Dec 20 18:34:13 trancelestial update-notifier.desktop[2804]: Cannot stat file /proc/2705/fd/13: Permission denied
Dec 20 18:34:13 trancelestial update-notifier.desktop[2804]: Cannot stat file /proc/2705/fd/17: Permission denied
Dec 20 18:34:13 trancelestial update-notifier.desktop[2804]: Cannot stat file /proc/2705/fd/18: Permission denied
Dec 20 18:34:13 trancelestial update-notifier.desktop[2804]: Cannot stat file /proc/2705/fd/19: Permission denied
Dec 20 18:34:13 trancelestial update-notifier.desktop[2804]: Cannot stat file /proc/2427/fd/1023: Permission denied
Dec 20 18:34:13 trancelestial update-notifier.desktop[2804]: Cannot stat file /proc/2608/fd/5: Permission denied
Dec 20 18:34:13 trancelestial update-notifier.desktop[2804]: Cannot stat file /proc/2608/fd/6: Permission denied
Dec 20 18:34:13 trancelestial update-notifier.desktop[2804]: Cannot stat file /proc/2608/fd/7: Permission denied
Dec 20 18:34:13 trancelestial update-notifier.desktop[2804]: Cannot stat file /proc/2608/fd/8: Permission denied
Dec 20 18:34:13 trancelestial update-notifier.desktop[2804]: Cannot stat file /proc/2608/fd/9: Permission denied
Dec 20 18:34:13 trancelestial update-notifier.desktop[2804]: Cannot stat file /proc/2608/fd/10: Permission denied
Dec 20 18:34:13 trancelestial update-notifier.desktop[2804]: Cannot stat file /proc/2608/fd/11: Permission denied
Dec 20 18:34:13 trancelestial update-notifier.desktop[2804]: Cannot stat file /proc/2608/fd/12: Permission denied
Dec 20 18:34:13 trancelestial update-notifier.desktop[2804]: Cannot stat file /proc/2608/fd/68: Permission denied
Dec 20 18:34:13 trancelestial update-notifier.desktop[2804]: Cannot stat file /proc/2608/fd/75: Permission denied
Dec 20 18:34:13 trancelestial update-notifier.desktop[2804]: Cannot stat file /proc/2608/fd/76: Permission denied
Dec 20 18:34:13 trancelestial update-notifier.desktop[2804]: Cannot stat file /proc/2608/fd/1023: Permission denied
Dec 20 18:34:13 trancelestial update-notifier.desktop[2804]: Cannot stat file /proc/2651/fd/6: Permission denied
Dec 20 18:34:13 trancelestial update-notifier.desktop[2804]: Cannot stat file /proc/2651/fd/7: Permission denied
Dec 20 18:34:13 trancelestial update-notifier.desktop[2804]: Cannot stat file /proc/2651/fd/8: Permission denied
Dec 20 18:34:13 trancelestial update-notifier.desktop[2804]: Cannot stat file /proc/2651/fd/9: Permission denied
Dec 20 18:34:13 trancelestial update-notifier.desktop[2804]: Cannot stat file /proc/2651/fd/10: Permission denied
Dec 20 18:34:13 trancelestial update-notifier.desktop[2804]: Cannot stat file /proc/2651/fd/11: Permission denied
Dec 20 18:34:13 trancelestial update-notifier.desktop[2804]: Cannot stat file /proc/2651/fd/12: Permission denied
Dec 20 18:34:13 trancelestial update-notifier.desktop[2804]: Cannot stat file /proc/2651/fd/13: Permission denied
Dec 20 18:34:13 trancelestial update-notifier.desktop[2804]: Cannot stat file /proc/2670/fd/4: Permission denied
Dec 20 18:34:13 trancelestial update-notifier.desktop[2804]: Cannot stat file /proc/2670/fd/6: Permission denied
Dec 20 18:34:13 trancelestial update-notifier.desktop[2804]: Cannot stat file /proc/2670/fd/7: Permission denied
Dec 20 18:34:13 trancelestial update-notifier.desktop[2804]: Cannot stat file /proc/2670/fd/8: Permission denied
Dec 20 18:34:13 trancelestial update-notifier.desktop[2804]: Cannot stat file /proc/2670/fd/9: Permission denied
Dec 20 18:34:13 trancelestial update-notifier.desktop[2804]: Cannot stat file /proc/2705/fd/6: Permission denied
Dec 20 18:34:13 trancelestial update-notifier.desktop[2804]: Cannot stat file /proc/2705/fd/7: Permission denied
Dec 20 18:34:13 trancelestial update-notifier.desktop[2804]: Cannot stat file /proc/2705/fd/8: Permission denied
Dec 20 18:34:13 trancelestial update-notifier.desktop[2804]: Cannot stat file /proc/2705/fd/9: Permission denied
Dec 20 18:34:13 trancelestial update-notifier.desktop[2804]: Cannot stat file /proc/2705/fd/10: Permission denied
Dec 20 18:34:13 trancelestial update-notifier.desktop[2804]: Cannot stat file /proc/2705/fd/11: Permission denied
Dec 20 18:34:13 trancelestial update-notifier.desktop[2804]: Cannot stat file /proc/2705/fd/12: Permission denied
Dec 20 18:34:13 trancelestial update-notifier.desktop[2804]: Cannot stat file /proc/2705/fd/13: Permission denied
Dec 20 18:34:13 trancelestial update-notifier.desktop[2804]: Cannot stat file /proc/2705/fd/17: Permission denied
Dec 20 18:34:13 trancelestial update-notifier.desktop[2804]: Cannot stat file /proc/2705/fd/18: Permission denied
Dec 20 18:34:13 trancelestial update-notifier.desktop[2804]: Cannot stat file /proc/2705/fd/19: Permission denied
Dec 20 18:34:13 trancelestial update-notifier.desktop[2804]: Cannot stat file /proc/2427/fd/1023: Permission denied
Dec 20 18:34:13 trancelestial update-notifier.desktop[2804]: Cannot stat file /proc/2608/fd/5: Permission denied
Dec 20 18:34:13 trancelestial update-notifier.desktop[2804]: Cannot stat file /proc/2608/fd/6: Permission denied
Dec 20 18:34:13 trancelestial update-notifier.desktop[2804]: Cannot stat file /proc/2608/fd/7: Permission denied
Dec 20 18:34:13 trancelestial update-notifier.desktop[2804]: Cannot stat file /proc/2608/fd/8: Permission denied
Dec 20 18:34:13 trancelestial update-notifier.desktop[2804]: Cannot stat file /proc/2608/fd/9: Permission denied
Dec 20 18:34:13 trancelestial update-notifier.desktop[2804]: Cannot stat file /proc/2608/fd/10: Permission denied
Dec 20 18:34:13 trancelestial update-notifier.desktop[2804]: Cannot stat file /proc/2608/fd/11: Permission denied
Dec 20 18:34:13 trancelestial update-notifier.desktop[2804]: Cannot stat file /proc/2608/fd/12: Permission denied
Dec 20 18:34:13 trancelestial update-notifier.desktop[2804]: Cannot stat file /proc/2608/fd/68: Permission denied
Dec 20 18:34:13 trancelestial update-notifier.desktop[2804]: Cannot stat file /proc/2608/fd/75: Permission denied
Dec 20 18:34:13 trancelestial update-notifier.desktop[2804]: Cannot stat file /proc/2608/fd/76: Permission denied
Dec 20 18:34:13 trancelestial update-notifier.desktop[2804]: Cannot stat file /proc/2608/fd/1023: Permission denied
Dec 20 18:34:13 trancelestial update-notifier.desktop[2804]: Cannot stat file /proc/2651/fd/6: Permission denied
Dec 20 18:34:13 trancelestial update-notifier.desktop[2804]: Cannot stat file /proc/2651/fd/7: Permission denied
Dec 20 18:34:13 trancelestial update-notifier.desktop[2804]: Cannot stat file /proc/2651/fd/8: Permission denied
Dec 20 18:34:13 trancelestial update-notifier.desktop[2804]: Cannot stat file /proc/2651/fd/9: Permission denied
Dec 20 18:34:13 trancelestial update-notifier.desktop[2804]: Cannot stat file /proc/2651/fd/10: Permission denied
Dec 20 18:34:13 trancelestial update-notifier.desktop[2804]: Cannot stat file /proc/2651/fd/11: Permission denied
Dec 20 18:34:13 trancelestial update-notifier.desktop[2804]: Cannot stat file /proc/2651/fd/12: Permission denied
Dec 20 18:34:13 trancelestial update-notifier.desktop[2804]: Cannot stat file /proc/2651/fd/13: Permission denied
Dec 20 18:34:13 trancelestial PackageKit: resolve transaction /2003_dbeceacb from uid 1000 finished with success after 372ms
Dec 20 18:34:13 trancelestial update-notifier.desktop[2804]: Cannot stat file /proc/2670/fd/4: Permission denied
Dec 20 18:34:13 trancelestial update-notifier.desktop[2804]: Cannot stat file /proc/2670/fd/6: Permission denied
Dec 20 18:34:13 trancelestial update-notifier.desktop[2804]: Cannot stat file /proc/2670/fd/7: Permission denied
Dec 20 18:34:13 trancelestial update-notifier.desktop[2804]: Cannot stat file /proc/2670/fd/8: Permission denied
Dec 20 18:34:13 trancelestial update-notifier.desktop[2804]: Cannot stat file /proc/2670/fd/9: Permission denied
Dec 20 18:34:13 trancelestial update-notifier.desktop[2804]: Cannot stat file /proc/2705/fd/6: Permission denied
Dec 20 18:34:13 trancelestial update-notifier.desktop[2804]: Cannot stat file /proc/2705/fd/7: Permission denied
Dec 20 18:34:13 trancelestial update-notifier.desktop[2804]: Cannot stat file /proc/2705/fd/8: Permission denied
Dec 20 18:34:13 trancelestial update-notifier.desktop[2804]: Cannot stat file /proc/2705/fd/9: Permission denied
Dec 20 18:34:13 trancelestial update-notifier.desktop[2804]: Cannot stat file /proc/2705/fd/10: Permission denied
Dec 20 18:34:13 trancelestial update-notifier.desktop[2804]: Cannot stat file /proc/2705/fd/11: Permission denied
Dec 20 18:34:13 trancelestial update-notifier.desktop[2804]: Cannot stat file /proc/2705/fd/12: Permission denied
Dec 20 18:34:13 trancelestial update-notifier.desktop[2804]: Cannot stat file /proc/2705/fd/13: Permission denied
Dec 20 18:34:13 trancelestial update-notifier.desktop[2804]: Cannot stat file /proc/2705/fd/17: Permission denied
Dec 20 18:34:13 trancelestial update-notifier.desktop[2804]: Cannot stat file /proc/2705/fd/18: Permission denied
Dec 20 18:34:13 trancelestial update-notifier.desktop[2804]: Cannot stat file /proc/2705/fd/19: Permission denied
Dec 20 18:34:13 trancelestial update-notifier.desktop[2804]: Cannot stat file /proc/2427/fd/1023: Permission denied
Dec 20 18:34:13 trancelestial update-notifier.desktop[2804]: Cannot stat file /proc/2608/fd/5: Permission denied
Dec 20 18:34:13 trancelestial update-notifier.desktop[2804]: Cannot stat file /proc/2608/fd/6: Permission denied
Dec 20 18:34:13 trancelestial update-notifier.desktop[2804]: Cannot stat file /proc/2608/fd/7: Permission denied
Dec 20 18:34:13 trancelestial update-notifier.desktop[2804]: Cannot stat file /proc/2608/fd/8: Permission denied
Dec 20 18:34:13 trancelestial update-notifier.desktop[2804]: Cannot stat file /proc/2608/fd/9: Permission denied
Dec 20 18:34:13 trancelestial update-notifier.desktop[2804]: Cannot stat file /proc/2608/fd/10: Permission denied
Dec 20 18:34:13 trancelestial update-notifier.desktop[2804]: Cannot stat file /proc/2608/fd/11: Permission denied
Dec 20 18:34:13 trancelestial update-notifier.desktop[2804]: Cannot stat file /proc/2608/fd/12: Permission denied
Dec 20 18:34:13 trancelestial update-notifier.desktop[2804]: Cannot stat file /proc/2608/fd/68: Permission denied
Dec 20 18:34:13 trancelestial update-notifier.desktop[2804]: Cannot stat file /proc/2608/fd/75: Permission denied
Dec 20 18:34:13 trancelestial update-notifier.desktop[2804]: Cannot stat file /proc/2608/fd/76: Permission denied
Dec 20 18:34:13 trancelestial update-notifier.desktop[2804]: Cannot stat file /proc/2608/fd/1023: Permission denied
Dec 20 18:34:13 trancelestial update-notifier.desktop[2804]: Cannot stat file /proc/2651/fd/6: Permission denied
Dec 20 18:34:13 trancelestial update-notifier.desktop[2804]: Cannot stat file /proc/2651/fd/7: Permission denied
Dec 20 18:34:13 trancelestial update-notifier.desktop[2804]: Cannot stat file /proc/2651/fd/8: Permission denied
Dec 20 18:34:13 trancelestial update-notifier.desktop[2804]: Cannot stat file /proc/2651/fd/9: Permission denied
Dec 20 18:34:13 trancelestial update-notifier.desktop[2804]: Cannot stat file /proc/2651/fd/10: Permission denied
Dec 20 18:34:13 trancelestial update-notifier.desktop[2804]: Cannot stat file /proc/2651/fd/11: Permission denied
Dec 20 18:34:13 trancelestial update-notifier.desktop[2804]: Cannot stat file /proc/2651/fd/12: Permission denied
Dec 20 18:34:13 trancelestial update-notifier.desktop[2804]: Cannot stat file /proc/2651/fd/13: Permission denied
Dec 20 18:34:13 trancelestial update-notifier.desktop[2804]: Cannot stat file /proc/2670/fd/4: Permission denied
Dec 20 18:34:13 trancelestial update-notifier.desktop[2804]: Cannot stat file /proc/2670/fd/6: Permission denied
Dec 20 18:34:13 trancelestial update-notifier.desktop[2804]: Cannot stat file /proc/2670/fd/7: Permission denied
Dec 20 18:34:13 trancelestial update-notifier.desktop[2804]: Cannot stat file /proc/2670/fd/8: Permission denied
Dec 20 18:34:13 trancelestial update-notifier.desktop[2804]: Cannot stat file /proc/2670/fd/9: Permission denied
Dec 20 18:34:13 trancelestial update-notifier.desktop[2804]: Cannot stat file /proc/2705/fd/6: Permission denied
Dec 20 18:34:13 trancelestial update-notifier.desktop[2804]: Cannot stat file /proc/2705/fd/7: Permission denied
Dec 20 18:34:13 trancelestial update-notifier.desktop[2804]: Cannot stat file /proc/2705/fd/8: Permission denied
Dec 20 18:34:13 trancelestial update-notifier.desktop[2804]: Cannot stat file /proc/2705/fd/9: Permission denied
Dec 20 18:34:13 trancelestial update-notifier.desktop[2804]: Cannot stat file /proc/2705/fd/10: Permission denied
Dec 20 18:34:13 trancelestial update-notifier.desktop[2804]: Cannot stat file /proc/2705/fd/11: Permission denied
Dec 20 18:34:13 trancelestial update-notifier.desktop[2804]: Cannot stat file /proc/2705/fd/12: Permission denied
Dec 20 18:34:13 trancelestial update-notifier.desktop[2804]: Cannot stat file /proc/2705/fd/13: Permission denied
Dec 20 18:34:13 trancelestial update-notifier.desktop[2804]: Cannot stat file /proc/2705/fd/17: Permission denied
Dec 20 18:34:13 trancelestial update-notifier.desktop[2804]: Cannot stat file /proc/2705/fd/18: Permission denied
Dec 20 18:34:13 trancelestial update-notifier.desktop[2804]: Cannot stat file /proc/2705/fd/19: Permission denied
Dec 20 18:34:14 trancelestial gnome-shell[1407]: [AppIndicatorSupport-DEBUG] Registering StatusNotifierItem :1.75/org/ayatana/NotificationItem/software_update_available
Dec 20 18:34:14 trancelestial boltd[1601]: probing: timeout, done: [2992401] (2000000)
Dec 20 18:34:28 trancelestial evolution-calen[2498]: e_cal_recur_generate_instances_sync: assertion 'icaltime_compare (interval_start, interval_end) < 0' failed
Dec 20 18:34:28 trancelestial evolution-calen[2498]: message repeated 17 times: [ e_cal_recur_generate_instances_sync: assertion 'icaltime_compare (interval_start, interval_end) < 0' failed]
Dec 20 18:34:28 trancelestial gnome-shell-cal[1573]: create_client_for_source: assertion 'client == NULL' failed
Dec 20 18:34:28 trancelestial evolution-calen[2498]: e_cal_recur_generate_instances_sync: assertion 'icaltime_compare (interval_start, interval_end) < 0' failed
Dec 20 18:34:28 trancelestial evolution-calen[2498]: message repeated 17 times: [ e_cal_recur_generate_instances_sync: assertion 'icaltime_compare (interval_start, interval_end) < 0' failed]
Dec 20 18:34:31 trancelestial boltd[1601]: power: got event for guard '2' (10)
Dec 20 18:34:31 trancelestial boltd[1601]: power: guard '2' for 'fwupd' deactivated
Dec 20 18:34:31 trancelestial boltd[1601]: power: shutdown scheduled (T-20,00s)
Dec 20 18:34:36 trancelestial PackageKit: search-file transaction /2004_bedaeaec from uid 1000 finished with success after 22621ms
Dec 20 18:34:37 trancelestial PackageKit: search-file transaction /2005_ebaebeda from uid 1000 finished with success after 382ms
Dec 20 18:34:37 trancelestial PackageKit: search-file transaction /2006_cedaadda from uid 1000 finished with success after 390ms
Dec 20 18:34:38 trancelestial PackageKit: search-file transaction /2007_bdbcaedd from uid 1000 finished with success after 379ms
Dec 20 18:34:38 trancelestial PackageKit: search-file transaction /2008_becddcca from uid 1000 finished with success after 358ms
Dec 20 18:34:38 trancelestial PackageKit: search-file transaction /2009_cbecbdcb from uid 1000 finished with success after 355ms
Dec 20 18:34:39 trancelestial PackageKit: search-file transaction /2010_dbbbceae from uid 1000 finished with success after 356ms
Dec 20 18:34:39 trancelestial PackageKit: search-file transaction /2011_acaccbdc from uid 1000 finished with success after 390ms
Dec 20 18:34:40 trancelestial PackageKit: search-file transaction /2012_eaeadadc from uid 1000 finished with success after 369ms
Dec 20 18:34:40 trancelestial PackageKit: search-file transaction /2013_edbdeddc from uid 1000 finished with success after 359ms
Dec 20 18:34:40 trancelestial PackageKit: search-file transaction /2014_daabbdbe from uid 1000 finished with success after 356ms
Dec 20 18:34:41 trancelestial PackageKit: search-file transaction /2015_aaecddae from uid 1000 finished with success after 364ms
Dec 20 18:34:41 trancelestial PackageKit: search-file transaction /2016_accbdabd from uid 1000 finished with success after 358ms
Dec 20 18:34:42 trancelestial PackageKit: search-file transaction /2017_eedbdcdb from uid 1000 finished with success after 354ms
Dec 20 18:34:42 trancelestial PackageKit: search-file transaction /2018_aaaedabb from uid 1000 finished with success after 351ms
Dec 20 18:34:42 trancelestial PackageKit: search-file transaction /2019_eccbbbcc from uid 1000 finished with success after 353ms
Dec 20 18:34:43 trancelestial PackageKit: search-file transaction /2020_abcbaeee from uid 1000 finished with success after 368ms
Dec 20 18:34:43 trancelestial PackageKit: search-file transaction /2021_edadbadd from uid 1000 finished with success after 375ms
Dec 20 18:34:44 trancelestial PackageKit: search-file transaction /2022_ddceccaa from uid 1000 finished with success after 363ms
Dec 20 18:34:44 trancelestial gnome-software[2797]: Failed to find one package for nvvp.desktop, /usr/share/applications/nvvp.desktop, [0]
Dec 20 18:34:44 trancelestial PackageKit: search-file transaction /2023_ebcdaeaa from uid 1000 finished with success after 363ms
Dec 20 18:34:45 trancelestial PackageKit: search-file transaction /2024_bdbceeea from uid 1000 finished with success after 354ms
Dec 20 18:34:45 trancelestial gnome-software[2797]: Failed to find one package for nsight.desktop, /usr/share/applications/nsight.desktop, [0]
Dec 20 18:34:45 trancelestial PackageKit: get-details transaction /2025_ddbcbdbc from uid 1000 finished with success after 323ms
Dec 20 18:34:51 trancelestial boltd[1601]: power: setting force_power to OFF
Dec 20 18:34:52 trancelestial upowerd[1413]: unhandled action 'unbind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.0/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:02.0/0000:3a:00.0/usb4/4-0:1.0
Dec 20 18:34:52 trancelestial upowerd[1413]: unhandled action 'unbind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.0/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:02.0/0000:3a:00.0/usb3/3-0:1.0
Dec 20 18:34:52 trancelestial boltd[1601]: [d6010000-0050-Pirates                    ] removed (/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.0/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:00.0/0000:04:00.0/domain0/0-0)
Dec 20 18:34:52 trancelestial boltd[1601]: [d6010000-0050-Pirates                    ] dbus: unexported
Dec 20 18:34:52 trancelestial upowerd[1413]: unhandled action 'unbind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.0/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:02.0/0000:3a:00.0/usb4
Dec 20 18:34:52 trancelestial upowerd[1413]: unhandled action 'unbind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.0/0000:02:00.0/0000:03:02.0/0000:3a:00.0/usb3
Dec 20 18:34:52 trancelestial kernel: [  151.072344] xhci_hcd 0000:3a:00.0: remove, state 4
Dec 20 18:34:52 trancelestial kernel: [  151.072349] usb usb4: USB disconnect, device number 1
Dec 20 18:34:52 trancelestial kernel: [  151.072600] xhci_hcd 0000:3a:00.0: USB bus 4 deregistered
Dec 20 18:34:52 trancelestial kernel: [  151.072606] xhci_hcd 0000:3a:00.0: xHCI host controller not responding, assume dead
Dec 20 18:34:52 trancelestial kernel: [  151.072609] xhci_hcd 0000:3a:00.0: remove, state 4
Dec 20 18:34:52 trancelestial kernel: [  151.072613] usb usb3: USB disconnect, device number 1
Dec 20 18:34:52 trancelestial kernel: [  151.072821] xhci_hcd 0000:3a:00.0: Host halt failed, -19
Dec 20 18:34:52 trancelestial kernel: [  151.072823] xhci_hcd 0000:3a:00.0: Host not accessible, reset failed.
Dec 20 18:34:52 trancelestial kernel: [  151.072906] xhci_hcd 0000:3a:00.0: USB bus 3 deregistered
Dec 20 18:34:52 trancelestial boltd[1601]: domain: 'domain0' removed
Dec 20 18:34:52 trancelestial boltd[1601]: dbus: domain0 unexported: ok
Dec 20 18:34:52 trancelestial kernel: [  151.573325] thunderbolt 0000:04:00.0: stopping RX ring 0
Dec 20 18:34:52 trancelestial kernel: [  151.573336] thunderbolt 0000:04:00.0: disabling interrupt at register 0x38200 bit 12 (0xffffffff -> 0xffffefff)
Dec 20 18:34:52 trancelestial kernel: [  151.573349] thunderbolt 0000:04:00.0: stopping TX ring 0
Dec 20 18:34:52 trancelestial kernel: [  151.573357] thunderbolt 0000:04:00.0: disabling interrupt at register 0x38200 bit 0 (0xffffffff -> 0xfffffffe)
Dec 20 18:34:52 trancelestial kernel: [  151.573364] thunderbolt 0000:04:00.0: control channel stopped
Dec 20 18:34:52 trancelestial kernel: [  151.573447] thunderbolt 0000:04:00.0: freeing RX ring 0
Dec 20 18:34:52 trancelestial kernel: [  151.573460] thunderbolt 0000:04:00.0: freeing TX ring 0
Dec 20 18:34:52 trancelestial kernel: [  151.573475] thunderbolt 0000:04:00.0: shutdown
Dec 20 18:34:52 trancelestial boltd[1601]: domain: 'domain0' removed
Dec 20 18:34:52 trancelestial kernel: [  151.612455] pci_bus 0000:03: Allocating resources
Dec 20 18:34:52 trancelestial kernel: [  151.612510] pcieport 0000:03:01.0: bridge window [io  0x1000-0x0fff] to [bus 05-39] add_size 1000
Dec 20 18:34:52 trancelestial kernel: [  151.612528] pcieport 0000:03:02.0: bridge window [io  0x1000-0x0fff] to [bus 3a] add_size 1000
Dec 20 18:34:52 trancelestial kernel: [  151.612533] pcieport 0000:03:02.0: bridge window [mem 0x00100000-0x000fffff 64bit pref] to [bus 3a] add_size 200000 add_align 100000
Dec 20 18:34:52 trancelestial kernel: [  151.612551] pcieport 0000:02:00.0: bridge window [io  0x1000-0x0fff] to [bus 03-3a] add_size 2000
Dec 20 18:34:52 trancelestial kernel: [  151.612559] pcieport 0000:02:00.0: BAR 13: no space for [io  size 0x2000]
Dec 20 18:34:52 trancelestial kernel: [  151.612562] pcieport 0000:02:00.0: BAR 13: failed to assign [io  size 0x2000]
Dec 20 18:34:52 trancelestial kernel: [  151.612567] pcieport 0000:02:00.0: BAR 13: no space for [io  size 0x2000]
Dec 20 18:34:52 trancelestial kernel: [  151.612570] pcieport 0000:02:00.0: BAR 13: failed to assign [io  size 0x2000]
Dec 20 18:34:52 trancelestial kernel: [  151.612580] pcieport 0000:03:02.0: BAR 15: no space for [mem size 0x00200000 64bit pref]
Dec 20 18:34:52 trancelestial kernel: [  151.612583] pcieport 0000:03:02.0: BAR 15: failed to assign [mem size 0x00200000 64bit pref]
Dec 20 18:34:52 trancelestial kernel: [  151.612587] pcieport 0000:03:01.0: BAR 13: no space for [io  size 0x1000]
Dec 20 18:34:52 trancelestial kernel: [  151.612590] pcieport 0000:03:01.0: BAR 13: failed to assign [io  size 0x1000]
Dec 20 18:34:52 trancelestial kernel: [  151.612593] pcieport 0000:03:02.0: BAR 13: no space for [io  size 0x1000]
Dec 20 18:34:52 trancelestial kernel: [  151.612596] pcieport 0000:03:02.0: BAR 13: failed to assign [io  size 0x1000]
Dec 20 18:34:52 trancelestial kernel: [  151.612602] pcieport 0000:03:02.0: BAR 15: no space for [mem size 0x00200000 64bit pref]
Dec 20 18:34:52 trancelestial kernel: [  151.612605] pcieport 0000:03:02.0: BAR 15: failed to assign [mem size 0x00200000 64bit pref]
Dec 20 18:34:52 trancelestial kernel: [  151.612608] pcieport 0000:03:02.0: BAR 13: no space for [io  size 0x1000]
Dec 20 18:34:52 trancelestial kernel: [  151.612611] pcieport 0000:03:02.0: BAR 13: failed to assign [io  size 0x1000]
Dec 20 18:34:52 trancelestial kernel: [  151.612614] pcieport 0000:03:01.0: BAR 13: no space for [io  size 0x1000]
Dec 20 18:34:52 trancelestial kernel: [  151.612617] pcieport 0000:03:01.0: BAR 13: failed to assign [io  size 0x1000]
Dec 20 18:34:56 trancelestial kernel: [  155.800210] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: AER: Multiple Corrected error received: id=00e0
Dec 20 18:34:56 trancelestial kernel: [  155.824660] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, id=00e0(Receiver ID)
Dec 20 18:34:56 trancelestial kernel: [  155.824663] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0:   device [8086:a110] error status/mask=00002001/00002000
Dec 20 18:34:56 trancelestial kernel: [  155.824664] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0:    [ 0] Receiver Error         (First)
Dec 20 18:34:57 trancelestial kernel: [  155.957566] pcieport 0000:03:00.0: Refused to change power state, currently in D3
Dec 20 18:34:57 trancelestial boltd[1601]: probing: removing /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.0/0000:02:00.0 from roots
Dec 20 18:34:57 trancelestial kernel: [  155.960549] pci_bus 0000:04: busn_res: [bus 04] is released
Dec 20 18:34:57 trancelestial kernel: [  155.960596] pci_bus 0000:05: busn_res: [bus 05-39] is released
Dec 20 18:34:57 trancelestial kernel: [  155.960632] pci_bus 0000:3a: busn_res: [bus 3a] is released
Dec 20 18:34:57 trancelestial kernel: [  155.960691] pci_bus 0000:03: busn_res: [bus 03-3a] is released
```

Comment: Look earlier: `boltd` is the daemon controlling your Thunderbolt port. Looks like it is reacting to a shutdown instruction that it *received*. All the "cannot stat file" messages may indicate that big slabs of the filesystem are already gone...also likely a reaction to a previous shutdown instruction.

Comment: Okay, that clarifies a bit. Still I can not seem to find a problem earlier. I will wait for the next time it happens and try to find process that issues instruction. Do you have any advice on what kind of text I should look for? Which processes can send that command to boltd?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. Reinstalled Ubuntu a few days ago. The bug occurred no more, but a few days later, it started to happen again :( I don't know why.
But I know that it has something to do with power management of the thunderbolt chip.

#### Explanation

The thunderbolt chip powers down after a timeout if no thunderbolt devices are connected. As soon as it is powered off, the kernel freezes.

Workarounds/solutions:

- For me the problem only occurred with bolt version 0.8-4 (and maybe with 0.7-2 I don't know anymore.) So I downgraded to version 0.5-0ubuntu0.18.04.1. No freezes anymore :)
- Simply connect a random thunderbolt device (this workaround is quite annoying)
- Type `boltctl power` in a terminal and do not abort it.
  Then the output of `boltctl power -q` should output something like this:

  ```
  supported: yes
  power state: on
  1 active power guards:
    guard '1'
     ├─ who: boltctl
     └─ pid: 4311
  ```

**EDIT:** Seems like [this bug at GitLAB](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/bolt/bolt/issues/146#note_170316) is the same.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone coming to this post, the actual problem for me was a hardware error. Namely, dead component in the touchpad panel.