# Computer Crashes Randomly when Unplugged

Tags: 18.04, shutdown

My computer (Acer Aspire running Ubuntu 18.04) continually crashes at random intervals when unplugged. The problem only seems to occur when the computer is actively running processes (I left the system log open for hours while unplugged, and then 15 minutes after using it more actively, it shut down. 
Temperature seems to be in the normal for cpu, nvidia gpu, and ssd drive.
SSD checks out as ok using Smart Data and self-tests.

Here is the syslog from just before the crash to right after:

```
    c 14 23:01:34 enneadecagon systemd[1639]: Started GNOME Terminal Server.
Dec 14 23:01:35 enneadecagon nautilus[2238]: gtk_widget_get_mapped: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
Dec 14 23:01:35 enneadecagon nautilus[2238]: gdk_window_is_visible: assertion 'GDK_IS_WINDOW (window)' failed
Dec 14 23:01:35 enneadecagon nautilus[2238]: gtk_widget_set_opacity: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
Dec 14 23:01:35 enneadecagon nautilus[2238]: gtk_widget_queue_draw: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
Dec 14 23:01:37 enneadecagon dbus-daemon[1702]: [session uid=1000 pid=1702] Activating via systemd: service name='org.gnome.zeitgeist.Engine' unit='zeitgeist.service' requested by ':1.78' (uid=1000 pid=2270 comm="zeitgeist-datahub " label="unconfined")
Dec 14 23:01:37 enneadecagon systemd[1639]: Starting Zeitgeist activity log service...
Dec 14 23:01:37 enneadecagon dbus-daemon[1702]: [session uid=1000 pid=1702] Activating via systemd: service name='org.gnome.zeitgeist.SimpleIndexer' unit='zeitgeist-fts.service' requested by ':1.79' (uid=1000 pid=2279 comm="/usr/bin/zeitgeist-daemon " label="unconfined")
Dec 14 23:01:37 enneadecagon dbus-daemon[1702]: [session uid=1000 pid=1702] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.zeitgeist.Engine'
Dec 14 23:01:37 enneadecagon systemd[1639]: Started Zeitgeist activity log service.
Dec 14 23:01:37 enneadecagon systemd[1639]: Starting Zeitgeist full-text search indexer...
Dec 14 23:01:37 enneadecagon zeitgeist-daemon[2279]: #033[31m[04:01:37.814187 WARNING]#033[0m zeitgeist-daemon.vala:127: Unable to parse version info!
Dec 14 23:01:37 enneadecagon zeitgeist-daemon[2279]: #033[31m[04:01:37.814841 WARNING]#033[0m zeitgeist-daemon.vala:127: Unable to parse version info!
Dec 14 23:01:37 enneadecagon zeitgeist-daemon[2279]: #033[31m[04:01:37.824696 WARNING]#033[0m zeitgeist-daemon.vala:127: Unable to parse version info!
Dec 14 23:01:37 enneadecagon zeitgeist-datah[2287]: zeitgeist-datahub.vala:227: Unable to get name "org.gnome.zeitgeist.datahub" on the bus!
Dec 14 23:01:37 enneadecagon dbus-daemon[1702]: [session uid=1000 pid=1702] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.zeitgeist.SimpleIndexer'
Dec 14 23:01:37 enneadecagon systemd[1639]: Started Zeitgeist full-text search indexer.
Dec 14 23:01:41 enneadecagon systemd-resolved[759]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
Dec 14 23:01:41 enneadecagon systemd-resolved[759]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
Dec 14 23:01:57 enneadecagon systemd[1]: Starting Stop ureadahead data collection...
Dec 14 23:01:57 enneadecagon systemd[1]: Started Stop ureadahead data collection.
Dec 14 23:01:58 enneadecagon systemd-resolved[759]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
Dec 14 23:01:58 enneadecagon systemd-resolved[759]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
Dec 14 23:01:59 enneadecagon rtkit-daemon[1276]: Supervising 1 threads of 1 processes of 1 users.
Dec 14 23:01:59 enneadecagon rtkit-daemon[1276]: message repeated 5 times: [ Supervising 1 threads of 1 processes of 1 users.]
Dec 14 23:01:59 enneadecagon rtkit-daemon[1276]: Successfully made thread 2865 of process 2777 (n/a) owned by '1000' RT at priority 10.
Dec 14 23:01:59 enneadecagon rtkit-daemon[1276]: Supervising 2 threads of 2 processes of 1 users.
Dec 14 23:02:01 enneadecagon rtkit-daemon[1276]: message repeated 6 times: [ Supervising 2 threads of 2 processes of 1 users.]
Dec 14 23:02:08 enneadecagon systemd-resolved[759]: Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
Dec 14 23:02:08 enneadecagon systemd-resolved[759]: message repeated 3 times: [ Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.]
Dec 14 23:02:18 enneadecagon rtkit-daemon[1276]: Supervising 2 threads of 2 processes of 1 users.
Dec 14 23:02:18 enneadecagon rtkit-daemon[1276]: Supervising 2 threads of 2 processes of 1 users.
Dec 14 23:02:19 enneadecagon gnome-software[2988]: plugin appstream took 1.3 seconds to do setup
Dec 14 23:02:19 enneadecagon gnome-software[2988]: enabled plugins: shell-extensions, desktop-categories, packagekit, packagekit-refine-repos, packagekit-upgrade, systemd-updates, packagekit-refresh, os-release, packagekit-offline, packagekit-local, fwupd, packagekit-proxy, packagekit-url-to-app, ubuntuone, appstream, odrs, steam, hardcoded-featured, packagekit-refine, hardcoded-popular, generic-updates, desktop-menu-path, rewrite-resource, hardcoded-blacklist, modalias, packagekit-history, provenance, provenance-license, icons, key-colors, key-colors-metadata
Dec 14 23:02:19 enneadecagon gnome-software[2988]: disabled plugins: dummy, repos, dpkg, epiphany, snap
Dec 14 23:02:19 enneadecagon dbus-daemon[931]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.fwupd' unit='fwupd.service' requested by ':1.115' (uid=1000 pid=2988 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-software --gapplication-service " label="unconfined")
Dec 14 23:02:19 enneadecagon systemd[1]: Starting Firmware update daemon...
Dec 14 23:02:19 enneadecagon fwupd[3042]: disabling plugin because: failed to startup dell: failed to initialize libsmbios library
Dec 14 23:02:19 enneadecagon fwupd[3042]: disabling plugin because: failed to coldplug amt: ME refused connection
Dec 14 23:02:19 enneadecagon fwupd[3042]: disabling plugin because: failed to coldplug synapticsmst: MST firmware updating not supported by OEM
Dec 14 23:02:19 enneadecagon fwupd[3042]: using plugins: upower, csr, nitrokey, udev, thunderbolt, ebitdo, steelseries, unifying, colorhug, wacomhid, dfu, altos, thunderbolt_power, uefi
Dec 14 23:02:19 enneadecagon fwupd[3042]: Daemon ready for requests
Dec 14 23:02:20 enneadecagon PackageKit: get-updates transaction /8658_ecedbcae from uid 1000 finished with success after 835ms
Dec 14 23:02:20 enneadecagon dbus-daemon[931]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.fwupd'
Dec 14 23:02:20 enneadecagon systemd[1]: Started Firmware update daemon.
Dec 14 23:02:20 enneadecagon gnome-software[2988]: hiding category productivity featured applications: found only 0 to show, need at least 9
Dec 14 23:02:20 enneadecagon gnome-software[2988]: Only 0 apps for recent list, hiding
Dec 14 23:02:20 enneadecagon gnome-shell[1895]: [AppIndicatorSupport-DEBUG] Registering StatusNotifierItem :1.89/org/ayatana/NotificationItem/software_update_available
Dec 14 23:02:20 enneadecagon gnome-shell[1895]: [AppIndicatorSupport-DEBUG] Registering StatusNotifierItem :1.89/org/ayatana/NotificationItem/livepatch
Dec 14 23:02:21 enneadecagon PackageKit: resolve transaction /8659_eeacaabe from uid 1000 finished with success after 677ms
Dec 14 23:02:21 enneadecagon PackageKit: resolve transaction /8660_bccebcde from uid 1000 finished with success after 410ms
Dec 14 23:02:21 enneadecagon gnome-software[2988]: hiding category graphics featured applications: found only 1 to show, need at least 9
Dec 14 23:02:21 enneadecagon PackageKit: resolve transaction /8661_becdeaae from uid 1000 finished with success after 420ms
Dec 14 23:02:21 enneadecagon gnome-software[2988]: Only 8 apps for popular list, hiding
Dec 14 23:02:22 enneadecagon PackageKit: resolve transaction /8662_daacdcae from uid 1000 finished with success after 414ms
Dec 14 23:02:22 enneadecagon PackageKit: search-file transaction /8663_ddaccada from uid 1000 finished with success after 469ms
Dec 14 23:02:23 enneadecagon PackageKit: search-file transaction /8664_cbaeeebc from uid 1000 finished with success after 429ms
Dec 14 23:02:23 enneadecagon PackageKit: search-file transaction /8665_dcaaaeaa from uid 1000 finished with success after 440ms
Dec 14 23:02:24 enneadecagon PackageKit: search-file transaction /8666_acabcccd from uid 1000 finished with success after 458ms
Dec 14 23:02:24 enneadecagon PackageKit: search-file transaction /8667_eabacedb from uid 1000 finished with success after 448ms
Dec 14 23:02:25 enneadecagon PackageKit: search-file transaction /8668_abebbcbe from uid 1000 finished with success after 460ms
Dec 14 23:02:25 enneadecagon PackageKit: search-file transaction /8669_bbadccda from uid 1000 finished with success after 454ms
Dec 14 23:02:25 enneadecagon PackageKit: search-file transaction /8670_dacebcad from uid 1000 finished with success after 459ms
Dec 14 23:02:26 enneadecagon PackageKit: search-file transaction /8671_dedccaac from uid 1000 finished with success after 448ms
Dec 14 23:02:26 enneadecagon PackageKit: search-file transaction /8672_debdbaeb from uid 1000 finished with success after 429ms
Dec 14 23:02:27 enneadecagon PackageKit: search-file transaction /8673_aaccacac from uid 1000 finished with success after 449ms
Dec 14 23:02:27 enneadecagon PackageKit: search-file transaction /8674_dacccbbd from uid 1000 finished with success after 472ms
Dec 14 23:02:28 enneadecagon PackageKit: search-file transaction /8675_bceaddcc from uid 1000 finished with success after 534ms
Dec 14 23:02:28 enneadecagon PackageKit: search-file transaction /8676_caeeaeec from uid 1000 finished with success after 460ms
Dec 14 23:02:28 enneadecagon gnome-software[2988]: Failed to find one package for arduino-arduinoide.desktop, /usr/share/applications/arduino-arduinoide.desktop, [0]
Dec 14 23:02:29 enneadecagon PackageKit: get-details transaction /8677_deeedbca from uid 1000 finished with success after 405ms
Dec 14 23:02:37 enneadecagon dbus-daemon[1702]: [session uid=1000 pid=1702] Activating service name='org.gnome.ControlCenter.SearchProvider' requested by ':1.25' (uid=1000 pid=1895 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-shell " label="unconfined")
Dec 14 23:02:37 enneadecagon dbus-daemon[1702]: [session uid=1000 pid=1702] Activating service name='org.gnome.Nautilus' requested by ':1.25' (uid=1000 pid=1895 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-shell " label="unconfined")
Dec 14 23:02:37 enneadecagon dbus-daemon[1702]: [session uid=1000 pid=1702] Activating service name='org.gnome.Calculator.SearchProvider' requested by ':1.25' (uid=1000 pid=1895 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-shell " label="unconfined")
Dec 14 23:02:37 enneadecagon dbus-daemon[1702]: [session uid=1000 pid=1702] Activating service name='org.gnome.Calendar' requested by ':1.25' (uid=1000 pid=1895 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-shell " label="unconfined")
Dec 14 23:02:37 enneadecagon dbus-daemon[1702]: [session uid=1000 pid=1702] Activating service name='org.gnome.seahorse.Application' requested by ':1.25' (uid=1000 pid=1895 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-shell " label="unconfined")
Dec 14 23:02:37 enneadecagon dbus-daemon[1702]: [session uid=1000 pid=1702] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.Calculator.SearchProvider'
Dec 14 23:02:37 enneadecagon dbus-daemon[1702]: [session uid=1000 pid=1702] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.ControlCenter.SearchProvider'
Dec 14 23:02:38 enneadecagon dbus-daemon[1702]: [session uid=1000 pid=1702] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.Nautilus'
Dec 14 23:02:38 enneadecagon dbus-daemon[1702]: [session uid=1000 pid=1702] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.Calendar'
Dec 14 23:02:38 enneadecagon dbus-daemon[1702]: [session uid=1000 pid=1702] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.seahorse.Application'
Dec 14 23:02:38 enneadecagon nautilus[3142]: g_key_file_load_from_file: assertion 'file != NULL' failed
Dec 14 23:02:38 enneadecagon nautilus[3142]: Could not establish a connection to Tracker: Failed to load SPARQL backend: Key file does not have group “DomainOntology”
Dec 14 23:02:38 enneadecagon nautilus[3142]: g_queue_pop_head: assertion 'queue != NULL' failed
```

Thanks so much for any help you can give me. I am at a complete loss on what to do.

Comment: Have you seen this https://askubuntu.com/questions/1103417/ubuntu-18-04-shuts-down-randomly?